# Next.js 13 and NextAuth: Caching Issue with Conditional Rendering Based on User Role in Production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I'm working on a Next.js 13 project with NextAuth for authentication. I have various user roles (admin, manager, etc.) and I'm doing conditional rendering in my based on these roles. However, when deployed to production, I encounter a caching issue (that's what i think) that affects the layout.

In the sidebar and header i show different routes based on the user's role. I'm using NextAuth to manage sessions.

In production, after logging in, i see the  previous user's layout. For example, if a 'manager' logs out and then an 'admin' logs in, the admin sees the 'manager' layout until the page is reloaded.

Here is a layout component:

```
export default async function DashboardLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const session: Session | null = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  return (
    <section className="min-h-screen">
      <div>
        <Sidebar session={session} />
        <div className="py-4 pl-2 pr-2 mx-auto lg:pr-4 lg:pl-24 lg:min-h-screen dashboard-container">
          <Header session={session} />
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

And in sidebar i do something like

```
{role === "admin" && (
        <Link
          href="/variables"
          className={`${
            pathname === "/variables" && "sidebar-active text-white"
          } flex items-center gap-1 shrink-0`}>
          <div className="flex center w-[30px] aspect-square shrink-0">
            <i className="text-xl bi bi-percent" />
          </div>
          {isHovering && <p className="text-bold">Variables</p>}
        </Link>
      )}
```

Reloading the page shows the correct layout based on the user role.

I can't figure out what's going on can someone help thank?